# IBM Cloud Storage client

Tags: java, sdk, ibm-cloud

I am trying to use IBM's Cloud Storage for uploading/downloading data - I use the free tier and IBM seems to have the best option available. I created credentials for my client as you can see from the picture (the JSON file is not shown for obvious reasons):

[image: IBM Cloud Storage]

I also created a bucket:

[image]

And the bucket has the service credentials linked to the bucket with read/write (role Writer) access, which can be seen here:

[image]

I then used the credentials (apikey, endpoints and resource_instance_id) from the JSON file in order to create the client:

```
{
  "apikey": "XXXX",
  "endpoints": "https://control.cloud-object-storage.cloud.ibm.com/v2/endpoints",
  "iam_apikey_description": "Auto-generated for key XXXX",
  "iam_apikey_name": "client-test",
  "iam_role_crn": "crn:v1:bluemix:public:iam::::serviceRole:Manager",
  "iam_serviceid_crn": "XXXX",
  "resource_instance_id": "XXXX::"
}
```

IBM has their own sdk for Java, so I added the maven dependency (ibm-cos-java-sdk version 2.5.4). I followed the example from their [documentation](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/cloud-object-storage/libraries?topic=cloud-object-storage-java) and created a separate class *IbmCloudClient*. The only difference I see is, I did not select a location, since I created a bucket that exists only on one location. So I forward `null` as a location value. The client code is the following:

```
package xyz.blackmonster.cloud;

import com.ibm.cloud.objectstorage.ClientConfiguration;
import com.ibm.cloud.objectstorage.auth.AWSCredentials;
import com.ibm.cloud.objectstorage.auth.AWSStaticCredentialsProvider;
import com.ibm.cloud.objectstorage.client.builder.AwsClientBuilder;
import com.ibm.cloud.objectstorage.oauth.BasicIBMOAuthCredentials;
import com.ibm.cloud.objectstorage.services.s3.AmazonS3;
import com.ibm.cloud.objectstorage.services.s3.AmazonS3ClientBuilder;
import com.ibm.cloud.objectstorage.services.s3.model.ListObjectsRequest;
import com.ibm.cloud.objectstorage.services.s3.model.ObjectListing;
import com.ibm.cloud.objectstorage.services.s3.model.S3ObjectSummary;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class IbmCloudClient {

    private AmazonS3 cloudClient;

    public IbmCloudClient(String apiKey, String resourceInstanceID, String endpointUrl) {
        AWSCredentials credentials;
        credentials = new BasicIBMOAuthCredentials(apiKey, resourceInstanceID);
        ClientConfiguration clientConfig = new ClientConfiguration().withRequestTimeout(5000);
        clientConfig.setUseTcpKeepAlive(true);
        cloudClient =
                AmazonS3ClientBuilder
                    .standard()
                    .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credentials))
                    .withEndpointConfiguration(new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration(endpointUrl, null))
                    .withPathStyleAccessEnabled(true)
                    .withClientConfiguration(clientConfig).build();
    }

    public List<String> listObjects() {
        ObjectListing objectListing = cloudClient.listObjects(new ListObjectsRequest().withBucketName("resume-storage"));
        List<String> files = objectListing.getObjectSummaries().stream().map(S3ObjectSummary::getKey).collect(Collectors.toList());

        return files;
    }
}
```

The main class, where we create the client to retrieve a list of bucket items:

```
package xyz.blackmonster.main;

import xyz.blackmonster.cloud.IbmCloudClient;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class IbmCloudRunner {

    public static void main(String[] arg) {
        String apiKey = "XXXX";
        String resourceInstanceID = "XXXX";
        String endpointUrl = "https://control.cloud-object-storage.cloud.ibm.com/v2/endpoints";

        IbmCloudClient client = new IbmCloudClient(apiKey, resourceInstanceID, endpointUrl);
        List<String> files = client.listObjects();
        System.out.println(files.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(", ")));
    }
}
```

When calling listObjects, I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.ibm.cloud.objectstorage.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Not Found (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 404; Error Code: 404 Not Found; Request ID: null), S3 Extended Request ID: null
    at com.ibm.cloud.objectstorage.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1712)
    at com.ibm.cloud.objectstorage.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1367)
    at com.ibm.cloud.objectstorage.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1113)
    at com.ibm.cloud.objectstorage.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:770)
    at com.ibm.cloud.objectstorage.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:744)
    at com.ibm.cloud.objectstorage.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:726)
    at com.ibm.cloud.objectstorage.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:686)
    at com.ibm.cloud.objectstorage.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:668)
    at com.ibm.cloud.objectstorage.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:532)
    at com.ibm.cloud.objectstorage.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:512)
    at com.ibm.cloud.objectstorage.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:3921)
    at com.ibm.cloud.objectstorage.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:3868)
    at com.ibm.cloud.objectstorage.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:3862)
    at com.ibm.cloud.objectstorage.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.listObjects(AmazonS3Client.java:779)
    at xyz.blackmonster.cloud.IbmCloudClient.listObjects(IbmCloudClient.java:36)
    at xyz.blackmonster.main.IbmCloudRunner.main(IbmCloudRunner.java:16)
```

I also tried to call `cloudClient.listBuckets()`, where I also got an exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.ibm.cloud.objectstorage.SdkClientException: Failed to parse XML document with handler class com.ibm.cloud.objectstorage.services.s3.model.transform.XmlResponsesSaxParser$ListAllMyBucketsHandler
    at com.ibm.cloud.objectstorage.services.s3.model.transform.XmlResponsesSaxParser.parseXmlInputStream(XmlResponsesSaxParser.java:156)
    at com.ibm.cloud.objectstorage.services.s3.model.transform.XmlResponsesSaxParser.parseListMyBucketsResponse(XmlResponsesSaxParser.java:348)
    at com.ibm.cloud.objectstorage.services.s3.model.transform.Unmarshallers$ListBucketsUnmarshaller.unmarshall(Unmarshallers.java:38)
    at com.ibm.cloud.objectstorage.services.s3.model.transform.Unmarshallers$ListBucketsUnmarshaller.unmarshall(Unmarshallers.java:34)
    at com.ibm.cloud.objectstorage.services.s3.internal.S3XmlResponseHandler.handle(S3XmlResponseHandler.java:65)
    at com.ibm.cloud.objectstorage.services.s3.internal.S3XmlResponseHandler.handle(S3XmlResponseHandler.java:34)
    at com.ibm.cloud.objectstorage.http.response.AwsResponseHandlerAdapter.handle(AwsResponseHandlerAdapter.java:70)
    at com.ibm.cloud.objectstorage.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1627)
    at com.ibm.cloud.objectstorage.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1336)
    at com.ibm.cloud.objectstorage.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1113)
    at com.ibm.cloud.objectstorage.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:770)
    at com.ibm.cloud.objectstorage.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:744)
    at com.ibm.cloud.objectstorage.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:726)
    at com.ibm.cloud.objectstorage.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:686)
    at com.ibm.cloud.objectstorage.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:668)
    at com.ibm.cloud.objectstorage.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:532)
    at com.ibm.cloud.objectstorage.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:512)
    at com.ibm.cloud.objectstorage.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:3921)
    at com.ibm.cloud.objectstorage.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:3868)
    at com.ibm.cloud.objectstorage.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:3862)
    at com.ibm.cloud.objectstorage.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.listBuckets(AmazonS3Client.java:881)
    at com.ibm.cloud.objectstorage.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.listBuckets(AmazonS3Client.java:887)
    at xyz.blackmonster.cloud.IbmCloudClient.listObjects(IbmCloudClient.java:37)
    at xyz.blackmonster.main.IbmCloudRunner.main(IbmCloudRunner.java:16)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:203)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:177)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:400)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:327)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(XMLScanner.java:1472)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:994)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:602)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:112)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:505)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:842)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:771)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
    at com.ibm.cloud.objectstorage.services.s3.model.transform.XmlResponsesSaxParser.parseXmlInputStream(XmlResponsesSaxParser.java:142)
    ... 23 more
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:53560', transport: 'socket'
```

Any idea what is wrong? Is it the code causing problems or did I not properly set up the bucket?

Comment: What is the `endpointUrl` that you are using? My guess is that you are declaring Path Style and using Virtual Host Style. Path Style: `https://{endpoint}/{bucket-name}`

Comment: I did not mask the endpoint above. I am using `"endpoints": "https://control.cloud-object-storage.cloud.ibm.com/v2/endpoints"` and for what I can tell, it does connect as it seems. And if you look up the code, I do specify the bucket name (which is _resume-storage_). The client itself is initialised, but once I make requests, I get exceptions.

Comment: The first elementary step in debugging a problem is too not assume anything. Your code does not show how you are calling `IbmCloudClient`. Therefore, I cannot tell from your question how that function is being called and with what parameters. Your error "typically" means you are using the wrong endpoint. If I knew the answer I would post an answer. Instead, I am providing a hint on what the problem might be. Edit your question so that we do not have to guess.

Comment: I do apologise for that, you are right. I added the main class, where I create the client. I would like to point out, I set the API key and resource instance ID manually (the main function has the strings). I know you have two options for credentials. One is to use a JSON file on a specific path, the other one is to manually set the right values, when creating a client. I opted for the second option as you can see. Hope that gives more insight @JohnHanley